# How to obtain id from array of object using angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays

I am trying to get id from array of object but `$scope.data.id` is coming undefined any idea what is implemented wrong or any better angularjs way to get data from array object ?

data

```
[{"_id":"57e540ab352e81329c984aba","name":"test diagram","owner":"wp6307","diagram":"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\r\n<definitions xmlns=\"http://www.omg.org/spec/BPMN/20100524/MODEL\"\r\n"}]
```

ctrl.js

```
diagramService.getDiagrams()
        .then(function (resp) {
          $scope.data = resp.data;
          console.log(JSON.stringify($scope.data));
          console.log($scope.data[0]._id); }
```

Comment: Shouldn it be $scope.data[0]["_id"] ?

Answer (score 0):

Plz try $scope.data[0]["_id"] instead of $scope.data[0]._id